# XSLT: Modify attribute if match in variable list?

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I'm trying to write XSLT code that will modify the ref attribute of bind element only if the beginning match one of the strings in variable oldRoot. This variable will be dynamic and will hold different number of strings in the production environment. My current solution worked for one string, but when I started to adopt it to many strings in the variable, the 'otherwise'-clause eclipsed the modification unless that match was for the last string. How do I break out this final "xsl:copy-of" -statement so that if only applies when none of the strings in the variable oldRoot matches? I only have access to XSLT 1.0.

**Simplified requirements:** I want the XSLT to edit the ref attribut of bind element where the beginning matches one of the strings in "list-variable" oldRoot. The edit should add the string '_1' to the end of the matched string.

Example input XML:

```
<Root>
<field>
    <bind ref="$.First.something.other"/>
</field>
<field>
    <bind ref="$.Second.subcat.name"/>
</field>
<field>
    <bind ref="$.Third.subcat.name"/>
</field>
<field>
    <bind ref="$.First"/>
    <field>
        <bind ref="$.subcat.date"/>
    </field>
</field>
<field>
    <bind ref="$.Third.subcat.date"/>
</field>
</Root>
```

Simplified XSL:

```
    <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:variable name="oldRoot" >
        <block>$.First</block>
        <block>$.Second</block>
    </xsl:variable> 
    <xsl:variable name="end" select="_1"/>

<!--    Identity rule.-->
    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

<!--    Rewrite attribute ref to work with new XML.-->
    <xsl:template match="*[local-name()='bind']/@ref">
        <xsl:variable name="attribute" select="."/>
        <xsl:for-each select="$oldRoot/block">
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="starts-with(substring-after($attribute,.),'.') or $attribute=.">
                    <xsl:attribute name="ref">
                        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                        <xsl:value-of select="$end"/>       
                        <xsl:value-of select="substring-after($attribute, .)"/>
                    </xsl:attribute>
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise>
                    <xsl:copy-of select="$attribute"/>
                </xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Result that i need:

```
<Root>
<field>
    <bind ref="$.First_1.something.other"/>
</field>
<field>
    <bind ref="$.Second_1.subcat.name"/>
</field>
<field>
    <bind ref="$.Third.subcat.name"/>
</field>
<field>
    <bind ref="$.First_1"/>
    <field>
        <bind ref="$.subcat.date"/>
    </field>
</field>
<field>
    <bind ref="$.Third.subcat.date"/>
</field>
</Root>
```

Comment: Could you explain in few simple words the rules that you want to be applied here? Also please clarify which XSLT processor you're using: your stylesheet is tagged `version="1.0"` but requires an XSLT 2.0 processor to run.

Comment: Why do you say this requires XSLT 2.0? (I will try to explain my rules even better soon in the original post.

Comment: Because `<xsl:for-each select="$oldRoot/block">` will fail in XSLT 1.0 unless you convert  the `$oldRoot` variable to a node-set first.

Comment: OK, thats odd. I use this stylesheet to debug in XMLSpy and it has not complained on the for-each.

Comment: Then you're not using an XSLT 1.0 processor.

Comment: @Björn XMLSpy supports XSLT 2.0 and I believe even the 3.0 draft.

Comment: Yes, but XMLSpy should read the version attribute of the stylesheet and select processor version acordingly, if their documentation is correct "The XSLT version of a stylesheet is specified in the version attribute of the xsl:stylesheet (or xsl:transform) element. XMLSpy contains the built-in Altova XSLT 1.0, Altova XSLT 2.0, and Altova XSLT 3.0 engines, and the appropriate engine is selected according to the value of the version attribute (1.0 or 2.0 or 3.0)."

Comment: You can easily determine which version your processor claims to support by getting the value of  `system-property('xsl:version')`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest you try it this way:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:exsl="http://exslt.org/common"
extension-element-prefixes="exsl">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:variable name="oldRoot" >
    <block>$.First</block>
    <block>$.Second</block>
</xsl:variable> 

<xsl:variable name="end" select="'_1'"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="bind/@ref">
    <xsl:variable name="match" select="exsl:node-set($oldRoot)/block[starts-with(current(), .)]"/>
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="$match">
            <xsl:attribute name="ref">
                <xsl:value-of select="$match"/>
                <xsl:value-of select="$end"/>
                <xsl:value-of select="substring-after(., $match)"/>
            </xsl:attribute>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:copy/>
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Applied to your input example, the result will be:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Root>
  <field>
    <bind ref="$.First_1.something.other"/>
  </field>
  <field>
    <bind ref="$.Second_1.subcat.name"/>
  </field>
  <field>
    <bind ref="$.Third.subcat.name"/>
  </field>
  <field>
    <bind ref="$.First_1"/>
    <field>
      <bind ref="$.subcat.date"/>
    </field>
  </field>
  <field>
    <bind ref="$.Third.subcat.date"/>
  </field>
</Root>
```

---

Note the added quotes in `<xsl:variable name="end" select="'_1'"/>`.

---

Unrelated to your question, but you should never use a hack like  `*[local-name()='bind']`. If your input uses a namespace, have your stylesheet use it too.

Comment: I need to use the "hack" since I don't know what namespaces I will encounter.

Comment: That is extremely rare - and it shouldn't happen at all. The namespaces used by the source XML are part of the source XML schema. If you don't know the namespaces you will encounter, how come you know the element and the attribute names and their hierarchy?